# FileInputStream path for exporting to jar

Tags: java, jar, inputstream, filepath, executable-jar

i am trying to export my project to .jar or .exe. This works fine expect for external text files.

Here my code:

```
    InputStream  is = new FileInputStream("MYPATH/start.txt");
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is);

  while ((my_char = r.read()) != -1) {
    text_list.add(String.valueOf((char) my_char));
  }
```

How do i have to set "MYPATH" so my jar-File works with text for other PCs?

Comment: If `start.txt` is a read only application resource, it should be included in the Jar and accessed by URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for

```
FileReader r = new FileReader(mypath + "/start.txt");
// or
FileReader r = new FileReader(new File(mypath, "start.txt"));
```

I wouldn't try creating a List of all the bytes as Strings.  Often reading a line at a time is more useful.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(mypath, "start.txt")));
for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
    // process line
}
```

Comment: I need this list for other stuff... but thats not the stuff...the problem is: for example at my PC my path is:/Users/username/Desktop/java/myProgramm/text/start.txt at another pc the path is /Users/username2/Test/myProgramm/text/start.txt ...for exporting to jar of course i can not hard coding the path in to my program but how do i that ?

Comment: You need to make `mypath` a variable which you get from somewhere e.g. the command line, a System property, user input. How you do that is up to you and depends on how your application works.

Answer (score 0):

```
  URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Interface/Text/start.txt");
  InputStream is = res.openStream();
   r = new InputStreamReader(is);             
   while ((my_char = r.read()) != -1) {
        text_list.add(String.valueOf((char) my_char));
    }
```

Thats my solution.